# What methods can I use for parameter estimation of fractional factorial design?

Tags: anova, estimation, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, fractional-factorial

I've been asked to estimate the parameters of fractional factorial design model which is normally estimated using least square method in R (code is lm).

**Question:** Is it possible to change the least squares method to another estimator such as weighted least squares or MLE?